# Passing variables by reference automatically

Tags: c#

I have this code sample. It passes the variable by reference, but it shouldnt (I dont think). I think it is defaulting to passing the variable by reference. I'm not sure what exactly to search for to find the documentation on this.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace CS_example_2
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int result = setResult();

                List<string> namesResult = new List<string>();
                setResultAr(namesResult);

                for (int i = 0; i < namesResult.Count; i += 1)
                {
                    if (i == result)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Result is " + namesResult[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.Console.ReadKey();
            }

            static int setResult()
            {
                int result = 3;
                return result;
            }

            static void setResultAr(List<string> namesResult)
            {
                List<string> res_array = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2", "item3, "item4", "item5" };

                foreach (string s in res_array)
                {
                    namesResult.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was hoping to find some MSDN documentation explaining this action.

Comment: C# always passes parameters `ByVal`, unless explicitly told to pass a reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I think it is defaulting to passing the variable by reference.

It is not.  It is passing the variable, which is a reference to a `List<string>`, by value.  Since `List<string>` is a reference type, you can modify it's content within the method.

You can see that the variable (`namesResult`) is not passed by reference if you try to *reassign the variable itself*, ie:

```
static void SetList(List<string> namesResult)
{
    List<string> res_array = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2", "item3, "item4", "item5" };
    namesResult = res_array; 
}
```

Doing the above will have no effect on the original variable, since it's passed by value.  If you passed it by reference (using `ref List<string>`), however, you would see that it can reassign the variable itself.

As for reading material on the subject, Jon Skeet wrote a great article on [Parameter Passing in C#](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) which discusses this in detail.

Comment: So how come in the method definition, when List<string> nameResult is defined, variable scope doesnt kick in and recognize this as a different variable than the nameResult defined in the static Main?

Comment: @Sugitime: it does - what makes you think that it does not?

Comment: @Sugitime It does - they're two distinctly different variables which *reference the same list*.  The variable is passed by value, but the object it's referring to does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on MSDN:

> A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by the reference, such as the value of a class member. However, you cannot change the value of the reference itself; that is, you cannot use the same reference to allocate memory for a new class and have it persist outside the block.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx

Because the namesResult value was never changed, this variable was still referencing the same data as the namesResult which was defined in the Main. So the variables are two separate variables, but the value contained within was a reference to the same data. Hence, any methods used from within the setResultAr method affect the referenced data.

Makes sense. Thank you guys.